# d3Plus move legend to the top

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I'm using d3Plus to create a treemap and a bar chart but the problem that I'm having is that the legend only shows after the chart, I would like to move that legend to show before the chart at the top. The reason for that is that the user has to scroll all the way down just to see the legend.

**Legend image**

[image]

Comment: According d3Plus documentation, `.legend()` do not have a `position` property. https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is painful because of the how `d3plus` animates (ie transitions) the various components of the chart as they load.  **But** you can move the legend yourself with something like:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>

<script>
  var data = [{
    "year": 1991,
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": 15
  }, {
    "year": 1991,
    "name": "beta",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "year": 1991,
    "name": "gamma",
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "year": 1991,
    "name": "delta",
    "value": 50
  }, {
    "year": 1992,
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": 20
  }, {
    "year": 1992,
    "name": "beta",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "year": 1992,
    "name": "gamma",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "year": 1992,
    "name": "delta",
    "value": 43
  }, {
    "year": 1993,
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": 30
  }, {
    "year": 1993,
    "name": "beta",
    "value": 40
  }, {
    "year": 1993,
    "name": "gamma",
    "value": 20
  }, {
    "year": 1993,
    "name": "delta",
    "value": 17
  }, {
    "year": 1994,
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": 60
  }, {
    "year": 1994,
    "name": "beta",
    "value": 60
  }, {
    "year": 1994,
    "name": "gamma",
    "value": 25
  }, {
    "year": 1994,
    "name": "delta",
    "value": 32
  }]
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .data(data)
    .type("bar")
    .id("name")
    .x("year")
    .y("value")
    .color("name")
    .legend(true)
    .draw();

  moveLegend();

  function moveLegend() {
    var l = d3.select("#key"),
        c = d3.select("#container");

    // wait for the legend and container to appear
    // if not wait 200 milliseconds and try again
    if (!l.size() || !c.size()) {
      setTimeout(moveLegend, 200);
    } else {
      // both now exist
      // move legend to top
      l.transition()
       .attr("transform","translate(0,0)");
      // move chart down height of legen
      var lh = l.node().getBBox().height;
      c.attr("transform", "translate(0," + lh + ")");
    }
    
  }
</script>
```